# DJI FPV Goggles Max Power option not available. Location: USA

Tags: fpv-goggles, united-states

I have a set of DJI FPV goggles but cannot change the Max Power option. It shows on the menu under the device section but I cannot select it.

- I am in the USA
- updated to latest firmware: V01.00.0500
- 2S 3000mAh battery
- `.txt` file on sd card `narco_pwr.txt` with `pwr_2` attribute in txt file
- **I have not powered or setup my Caddx Vista.**

Max Power is  set to 25mW and I cannot change it.

Comment: Have you tried putting a text file called ```naco.txt``` in the SD root, containing only the number ```1``` (to set to US mode?)

Comment: I see you state that you have not powered on or setup your Caddx Vista.  Is it possible that you can't change these settings unless the goggles are bound to a powered up vista or air unit?  I have not personally tested that yet, but that might be your issue.

Comment: @5zero7rc, yes it is possible that the goggles need to bound with the Vista or air unit. But right now I do not have the supplies to test that, and am trying to get verification if this is so.

Comment: @Kralc, I'm in the US, and it has 8ch, so I believe its already in US mode. But yes, I did add the naco.txt file with 1 within the txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't know if the "hack" has worked until you also have a Vista or Air unit bound to the goggles.

As a quick test, I powered up my goggles and left everything else off.  If I go to where you can adjust the power output it only shows 25mw and is grayed out.

As soon as I power up the rest of the system and the goggles connect to my air unit, I can change power output and other settings.  There are a number of options that require the air unit or vista to be powered on before you can change them.  I assume that information must be stored on the air unit side, not in the goggles.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation 